# How to find the include path for string.h in xcode

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

I am getting sick of seeing the warning

"Declaration of 'index' shadows a global declaration"

index is defined in string.h. I don't think that it's required for anything I am using and I really don't want to change all the local vars from index to something else.

Anyone know of a way to find out how (by what path) string.h is included? Is it possible to prevent it from being included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `index` function is actually declared in `/usr/include/strings.h`, and is marked as removed as of POSIX issue 7.  You can hide its declaration by setting the appropriate POSIX version with the compiler flag `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809`.  This will also hide other functions deprecated in issue 7, like `bcopy` and `bzero`.

Answer (score 0):

I find `-Wshadow` *extremely* annoying and rarely useful. Even if you solve this one case, there are bound to be others in the future, especially since system headers may define non-standard functions and variables which yours unintentionally shadow.

Personally, I would just disable the warning, and manually make sure no variables, functions, etc. are named the same as something being used.

Comment: C and C++ have namespaces explicitly reserved for the implementation (such as names beginning with underscores followed by capital letters), and the system libraries should stick to those.  If you shadow something that isn't reserved, and it causes any problems, report it as a bug.

Comment: @David: In this case, we're talking about a POSIX function required for UNIX compatibility.  The system library implementors don't have the option of using one of the reserved names.  If you don't want the POSIX extensions, you can specify that to the compiler.